# Copy value of entire row and past it into a different worksheet

Tags: excel, copy, vba

I have the following code:

```
  Option Explicit

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim myCell2 As Range
Dim oWkSht As Worksheet



Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'-------------------------------------------
'//Head Row A1\\
'-------------------------------------------
Range("A1").Value = "Department"
Range("B1").Value = "AOS Location"
Range("C1").Value = "Article Number"
Range("D1").Value = "HFB"
Range("E1").Value = "Article Name"
Range("F1").Value = "General Comments"
Range("G1").Value = "Home Location"
Range("H1").Value = "A. Stock"
Range("I1").Value = "SGF"
Range("J1").Value = "Incoming Good"
Range("K1").Value = "M.P.QTY"
Range("L1").Value = "Pallet Qty"
Range("M1").Value = "Start Date"
Range("N1").Value = "AOS SSS"
Range("O1").Value = "End Date"
Range("P1").Value = "End Qty"
Range("Q1").Value = "Promotion week"
Range("R1").Value = "Start-Up Qty"
Range("S1").Value = "Old AWS"
Range("T1").Value = "Goal"
Range("U1").Value = "QTY Sold LW"
Range("V1").Value = "Price"
Range("W1").Value = "GM0"
Range("X1").Value = "Sales Before"
Range("Y1").Value = "Sales this Month"
Range("Z1").Value = "Total Sold this month"
'-----------------------------------------------------------------
'//Date\\
'-----------------------------------------------------------------
Dim FirstDate As Date
Dim LastDate As Date
Dim NextDate As Date

Dim r As Long

Range("AA1").Value = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), 1)

FirstDate = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), 1)
LastDate = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date) + 1, 0)
r = 28
Do
 FirstDate = FirstDate + 1
 Cells(1, r) = FirstDate
 r = r + 1
Loop Until FirstDate = LastDate

LastRow = Range("A100000").End(xlUp).Row

Range("Y2").Formula = "=SUM(Registration!AA2:Registration!BE2)"

    Range("Y2").Select
    Range("Y2:Y" & LastRow).Select
    Selection.FillDown

Range("Z2").Formula = "=Registration!Y2*Registration!V2"
    Range("Z2").Select
    Range("Z2:Z" & LastRow).Select
    Selection.FillDown
    Selection.NumberFormat = _
        "_([$€-x-euro2] * #,##0.00_);_([$€-x-euro2] * (#,##0.00);_([$€-x-euro2] * ""-""??_);_(@_)"

'--------------------------------------------------
'//Format Head, Row A1\\
'--------------------------------------------------
Range("A1", Range("XFD1").End(xlToLeft)).Select

With Selection.Font
    .Name = "Calibri"
    .FontStyle = "Bold"
    .Size = 13

End With
'--------------------------------------------------
'//Select Used rows and column and shift one row down\\
'--------------------------------------------------

Range("A1", Range(Range("A1:A" & LastRow), Range("A1", Range("XFD1").End(xlToLeft)))).Offset(1).Select

With Selection.Font
    .Name = "Calibri"
    .FontStyle = "Regular"
    .Size = 11
End With
'--------------------------------------------------
'//Autofit and Align all cells in rows and columns\\
'--------------------------------------------------
With Cells
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
    .EntireRow.AutoFit
    .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
End With
'--------------------------------------------------
'//This Code will freeze the first row in the worksheet\\
'--------------------------------------------------
        With ActiveWindow
            .SplitColumn = 6
            .SplitRow = 1
           .FreezePanes = True
        End With
'--------------------------------------------------
'//This code will delete all of the old products and replace them to the sheet old_products.\\
'--------------------------------------------------
Dim l As Long

Dim dst As Range
Dim sht As Worksheet: Set sht = Worksheets("Old_Products")
With Sheets("Registration")
  For l = 2 To LastRow
    If .Cells(l, 6).Value = "old product" Then
      Set dst = sht.Range("F" & sht.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, -5)
      .Cells(l, 6).EntireRow.Copy
      dst.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
      .Cells(l, 6).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
  Next l
End With

'--------------------------------------------------
'//Sorting Column A in Department order\\
'--------------------------------------------------
Dim oRangeSort As Range
Dim oRangeKey As Range
' one range that includes all colums to sort
Set oRangeSort = Range("A1", Range(Range("A1:A" & LastRow), Range("A1", Range("XFD1").End(xlToLeft))))
' start of column with keys to sort
Set oRangeKey = Range("A2")

'//custom sort order\\

Dim sCustomList(1 To 28) As String

sCustomList(1) = "OTW showroom"
sCustomList(2) = "Launch Area"
sCustomList(3) = "Living"
sCustomList(4) = "Media"
sCustomList(5) = "Dining"
sCustomList(6) = "Kitchen"
sCustomList(7) = "Work"
sCustomList(8) = "Sleeping"
sCustomList(9) = "Storage"
sCustomList(10) = "Children"
sCustomList(11) = "Familly"
sCustomList(12) = "Staircase"
sCustomList(13) = "Lift"
sCustomList(14) = "OTW"
sCustomList(15) = "Koken en Eten"
sCustomList(16) = "Textiel"
sCustomList(17) = "Bed"
sCustomList(18) = "Bad"
sCustomList(19) = "Home Organisation"
sCustomList(20) = "Lighting"
sCustomList(21) = "Rugs"
sCustomList(22) = "Wall"
sCustomList(23) = "Home Decoration"
sCustomList(24) = "Self Storage"
sCustomList(25) = "CheckOut"
sCustomList(26) = "Cash Line"
sCustomList(27) = "AS IS"
sCustomList(28) = "SWFOOD"

Application.AddCustomList ListArray:=sCustomList

Sort.SortFields.Clear
oRangeSort.Sort Key1:=Range("A1:A" & LastRow), Order1:=xlAscending, Key2:=Range("B1:B" & LastRow), Order2:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, OrderCustom:=Application.CustomListCount + 1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal

' clean up
ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Clear
Application.DeleteCustomList Application.CustomListCount
'-------------------------------------------------------
'//This code will compare the sart date for the new product and
'if it's more than one day then it will removes the product from the Registration sheet to the Planned New Products.\\
'-------------------------------------------------------
Dim j As Integer

    For j = 2 To LastRow

If Sheets("Registration").Cells(j, "M").Value > Date + 1 Then
Sheets("Registration").Cells(j, "M").EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Planned_New_Products").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
Sheets("Registration").Cells(j, "M").EntireRow.Delete

End If

    Next j

''// Stop flickering...
'--------------------------------------------------

Range("A2").Select

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

This code copies the entire row based on the inserted text in column F and pastes the row in a different sheet. Now the problem is that I have the following code in column Y

```
=SUM(Registration!AA2:Registration!BE2)   'the number is from 2 to lastrow
```

And the following code in column Z

```
=Registration!Y2*Registration!V2          'the number is from 2 to lastrow
```

Now my question is how can I only copy the value of this entire row and paste it into a different worksheet?

Answer (score 0):

To copy the entire row of values:

```
Dim dst As Range
Dim sht As Worksheet: Set sht = Worksheets("Old_Products")
With Sheets("Registration")
  For l = lastRow to 2 Step -1
    If .Cells(l, 6).Value = "old product" Then
      Set dst = sht.Range("F" & sht.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, -5)
      .Cells(l, 6).EntireRow.Copy
      dst.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
      .Cells(l, 6).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
  Next l
End With
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Amorpheuses. I want to ensure that the formulas in columns Y and Z are Transferd as Values. I tried your answer and replaced xlPasteFormulas with xlPasteValues but it keeps repeating for a long time and at the end gives error that Method of range of Object _ worksheet faild. error 2147417848(80010108)

Comment: error is on this line        Set dst = Sheets("Old_Products").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

Comment: still the same. it seems that it  does find the right row but it copies the same row for almost 60 times and then past it for 60 times in the different sheet. so it does copy and past the value in the right sheet. but it just keeps doing it multiple time. i just want this to find the row copie the value of the entire row past it on the last row in the next sheet.

Comment: Looks like you are deleting rows but then keeping the same row count.  So if you delete row 2 then the next row to process was row 3 but now becomes row 2.  So your looping has to change to deal with that.  If you don't care what order your old products rows are in then you can loop from the top to the bottom - that will definitely work.   See the latest revision.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Amorpheuses. but i still get the same problem. I just posted my entire code. here.

Comment: You still have `For l=2 to lastRow` in the code you posted instead of `For l=lastRow to 2 Step -1`.  Did you try looping from lastRow to 2?

Comment: Okay I think it has to do that you have your code in 'Worksheet_Activate'.  Every time you select your worksheet (either manually or via code) it will run it - you don't want that.  You should move the code from it and make it into a regular subroutine in a module.  The headers you write into the sheet can be put into 'Workbook_Open' which is only run once when the worksheet is opened.